# Trigger para actualizar stock de un producto?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, trigger

Hola tengo una pregunta cómo hago para crear un trigger para descontar el stock, es que tengo 4 tablas una de producto, una de detalle de venta que tiene relacionado la tabla artículo, una de artículo, y una que se llama producto_articulo está tiene las llaves foráneas de producto y artículo y además tiene un campo de cantidad,
Lo que necesito es que cuando se cree un nuevo registro en la tabla detalles de venta busque el o los productos asociados al artículo, y que reste la cantidad a el stock en la tabla productos.

He intentado hacer lo siguiente pero no se como hacerlo, me da error,intento crear un for each dentro del for each row, para que itere los productos asociados al articulo y vaya descontado en la tabla producto, pero el segundo for me da error y ademas no se como hacer referencia a la tabla producto_articulo que es donde se encuentra la relacion con articulo y por tanto contiene los articulos y productos asociados.
Les agradeceria que me puedan ayudar a soluucionarlo o encontrar otra solucion, no se si esto se pueda hacer desde java con el framework de spring, con JPA.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`myacompany`@`%` TRIGGER `descontar_producto` AFTER INSERT ON `detalles_venta` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN

FOR EACH
BEGIN
DECLARE idP int default 0:
DECLARE cantidad int default 0:
SET idp=new.Det_id_articulo.id_producto;
SET cantidad=new.Det_id_articulo.cantidad;


UPDATE producto set Pro_stock=Pro_stock-cantidad  where id_producto=idP;

END
END
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Comment: Como sugerencia para preguntas futuras, no resumas los errores. "Me sale error" es una pésima forma de contar qué pasa. Incluye en tus próximas preguntas el mensaje de error completo, como texto.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Casi lo tienes y únicamente necesitas MySQL. En primer lugar, tabula tu código y te darás cuenta de que has escrito `FOR EACH ROW` dos veces y usas `:` en vez de `;`. Debería algo más parecido a esto:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`myacompany`@`%` TRIGGER `descontar_producto`
  AFTER INSERT ON `detalles_venta` FOR EACH ROW 
  BEGIN
  DECLARE idP int default 0;
  DECLARE cantidad int default 0;
  SET idp=new.Det_id_articulo.id_producto;
  SET cantidad=new.Det_id_articulo.cantidad;
  UPDATE producto set Pro_stock=Pro_stock-cantidad  where id_producto=idP;
  END;
```

En segundo lugar, y más importante, debes tener en cuenta que la venta de un artículo no implica descontar un único producto. Es decir, vender una tortilla no implica descontar un huevo, sino una cantidad proporcional que tengas definida en la tabla `producto_articulo`.

Voy a replicar la estructura de datos mínima de tu base de datos para generar el disparador que necesitas y comprobar su funcionamiento:

```
CREATE TABLE `detalles_venta`(
  Det_cantidad int,
  Det_idarticulo int  
  );
CREATE TABLE producto_articulo(
  ProArt_id_producto int,
  ProArt_id_articulo int,
  cantidad float
  );
CREATE TABLE producto(
  id_producto int,
  Pro_stock float
  );
```

Ahora vamos a suponer que tienes 10 huevos y 20 kg de patatas;

```
INSERT INTO producto (id_producto, Pro_stock)
  VALUES (1,10),(2,20);
```

Y que, para hacer 1 tortilla, necesitas 2 huevos y 3 kgs de patatas

```
INSERT INTO producto_articulo (ProArt_id_producto, ProArt_id_articulo, cantidad)
  VALUES (1,1,2),(2,1,3);
```

Tu tabla de stock debería tener este aspecto:

```
+-------------+-----------+
| id_producto | Pro_stock |
+-------------+-----------+
|           1 |        10 |
|           2 |        20 |
+-------------+-----------+
```

Y, una vez vendida 1 tortilla, debería quedar así:

```
+-------------+-----------+
| id_producto | Pro_stock |
+-------------+-----------+
|           1 |         8 |
|           2 |        17 |
+-------------+-----------+
```

Para ello, el disparador podría ser como éste:

```
CREATE TRIGGER descontar_producto_after_insert
  AFTER INSERT ON `detalles_venta` FOR EACH ROW 
  UPDATE producto JOIN (
      SELECT ProArt_id_producto,cantidad
        FROM producto_articulo
        WHERE ProArt_id_articulo=new.Det_idarticulo
    ) c1 ON id_producto=ProArt_id_producto
    SET Pro_stock=Pro_stock-(cantidad*new.Det_cantidad);
```

Primero busco todos los productos relacionados con ese artículo, me quedo con las cantidades y después las descuento del stock con un `UPDATE` y un `JOIN`, evitanto así el cursor al que creo que haces referencia con el `foreach` que comentas.

Lo más importante de este ejercicio no es el disparador, ni el `UPDATE` con el `JOIN`, sino que montes el ejemplo tú mismo siendo consciente en todo momento de lo que estás haciendo. Mi recomendación es que practiques bien este tipo de `UPDATE` y los `TRIGGER` por separado antes de trabajar con ambos a la vez. Sobre todo, por lo difíciles que son de depurar combinados.

Espero que te haya resultado útil. Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: Hola David, muchas gracias, el codigo funciona prefectamente, me ahorro mucho tiempo tu respuesta, si algo solo faltaba multiplicar el det_cantidad, pero lo logre solucionar.

Comment: CREATE TRIGGER descontar_producto_after_insert
  AFTER INSERT ON `detalles_venta` FOR EACH ROW 
  UPDATE producto JOIN (
      SELECT ProArt_id_producto,cantidad
        FROM producto_articulo
        WHERE ProArt_id_articulo=new.Det_idarticulo
    ) c1 ON id_producto=ProArt_id_producto
    SET Pro_stock=Pro_stock-(cantidad * new.Det_cantidad);

Comment: Tienes toda la razón, modifico la respuesta para que quede bien escrita. Entonces, ¿te funcionó? :)

Comment: Si funciono, gracias por la ayuda.